# Как отфильтровать одну коллекцию по другой?

Tags: java, java-stream, set

Есть 2 сета, у user много полей, но необходимое это departmentId, так же мне передали массив id на удаление, и то и то Стриг.
Как можно пройтись по oldUser и оставив только тех пользователей чьи departmentId есть в removeUserById?
Ниже стрим, который написал Но он не работает, закидывает проходят все, user без исключений

```
Set<User> oldEmploee = serRepository.findAllByDepartmentId(departmentId);
Set<String> newEmploee = command.getUser();
Set<User> abc = oldEmploee.stream().filter(e -> !newEmploee.contains(e.getDepartmentId())).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: @AlexKrass косяк в написании, исправил.
в newEmploee у меня лежат id юзеров в виде стринга
в oldEmploee юзеры которых вытащил из бд, и у них надо заменить поле getDepartmentId на дефолтное значение, но только тех юзеров, чьи id лежат в newEmploee.

Set<User> oldEmploee = userRepository.findAllByDepartmentId(departmentId);
Set<String> newEmploee = command.getEmployees();
Set<User> abc = oldEmploee.stream().filter(e -> !newEmploee.contains(e.getDepartmentId())).collect(Collectors.toSet());
abc.forEach(user -> user.setDepartmentId("3a9b4a8a-9e8c-4b72-b3cd"));
userRepository.saveAll(abc);

Comment: Да, увидел что описание поправили, поэтому удалил больше не нужные комментарии. Если у вас в newEmploee лежат ID юзеров, то и фильтровать мы должны тогда по ID юзеров же. То есть вместо `newEmploee.contains(e.getDepartmentId())` мы же должны сравнивать `newEmploee.contains(e.getId())`? Ну с точки зрения синтаксиса все правильно, в логике где-то ошибка.

Comment: @AlexKrass
Set<User> abc = oldEmploee.stream().filter(e -> newEmploee.contains(e.getId())).collect(Collectors.toSet());

да, ты был прав, "e.getId()" видимо на джуне мне еще долго сидеть :D
Спасибо!

Comment: Да не за что, все делают ошибки, с опытом научитесь их находить и править чуть быстрее)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

было:
Set abc = oldEmploee.stream().filter(e -> !newEmploee.contains(**e.getDepartmentId()**)).collect(Collectors.toSet());

стало:
Set abc = oldEmploee.stream().filter(e -> newEmploee.contains(**e.getId()**)).collect(Collectors.toSet());

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin так лучше?)